# creating custom page in powerschool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to create a custom page in powerschool (test server). I have written some piece of code. Actually the problem is that the script is never getting triggered. i was thinking that script will get fired since the password textbox has the keyup event on it. Not sure that i am doing it right. I am new to web pages. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- start right frame -->
<head>
<title>Student Information</title>
</head>
<body>

<form  id="StudentInformationForm" action="/admin/changesrecorded.white.html" method="POST">

<!-- start of content and bounding box -->
<div class="box-round">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="linkDescList">
<colgroup><col><col></colgroup>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="headerRow">
    <td colspan="2" class="bold">-Student Information</td>
</tr>

<tr class="Information">
    <td>
        <div>
            <label>Student Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="studentEmailAddress" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Student Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="studentWebPassword" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Grade</label>
            <label name="studentGrade">3<label/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button name="submit" type="button" disabled>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$j(function(){
$j("body").on("keyup","input[name='studentWebPassword']",function(){

var current_password = $j("input[name='studentWebPassword']").val();
var studentGrade = $j("input[name='studentGrade']").val();
var password_valid = true;
var hasNumber = /\d/;
var hasSpeacialCharacters=/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/;

if(studentGrade>=6) //for the students in Grade 3 to 6
{
//password should be of 5 characters and must contain a number
    if (current_password.length<5 && current_password>8 && !hasNumber.test(current_password))
    {
    password_valid=false;
    }

}

if (password_valid && current_password!='') {
$j("#submit").show();
} 
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html><!-- end right frame -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is never assigned to `$j`.
You can either replace `$j` with `$` or just add `$j = $` in the beginning of the script.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmy02goL/) with the added fix of `$j = $`

The issue with your script is that you are calling an id that doesn't exist `$j("#submit")` as `<button name="submit" type="button" disabled>Submit</button>` doesn't have an id. Additionally the `show` function doesn't remove the `disabled` attribute, you will want to use `prop('disabled', false)`.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmy02goL/4/) with the script fixed and `$j = $` fixed as well.